# Puppeteer: button won't click

Tags: puppeteer

It doesn’t seem like the ‘Sign in’ button is getting clicked.  I have included the code for the ‘sign in’ button of the web page below. Can someone help me find a way to get the ‘sign in’ button clicked please. This is the code I am using:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
  const page = (await browser.pages())[0];
  await page.goto("https://en.annonce123.com/login.php");
  const title = await page.title();


  await page.click('[name=username]');
  await page.keyboard.type(accountUser);
  await page.click('[name=password]');
  await page.keyboard.type(accPassword);

  await page.click('[name=login]');     //Here is the button that won't get clicked

  //await browser.close(); 
})();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found it:

```
  await page.click('input[name=login]');
```